# pyspark dataframe to get top 5 rows using sql or pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get top 5 items for each district based on rate_increase.
I am trying to use spark.sql as below:

Input:

```
   district   item   rate_increase(%)
     Arba     coil    500
     Arba     pen    -85
     Arba     hat     50
     Cebu     oil    -40
     Cebu     pen     1100
```

`Top5item = spark.sql('select district, item , rate_increase, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY district ORDER BY rate_increase DESC) AS RowNum from rateTable where rate_increase > 0')`

And this works.
How to filter top 5 products in the same statement. I tried as below and is tehre a better way to do via spar.sql?

```
Top5item = spark.sql('select district, item from (select NCSA, Product, growthRate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NCSA ORDER BY growthRate DESC) AS RowNum from rateTable where rate_increase > 0) where RowNum <= 5 order by NCSA')
```

output:

```
   district   item   rate_increase(%)
     Arba     coil    500
     Arba     hat     50
     Cebu     pen     1100
```

Thanks.

Comment: Actually for some reasons, DESC is not working. Whats the nest way to groupby(district) and take the top 5 items? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with pandas as a simple solution.

```
Top5item = df.sort_values('rate_increase(%)', ascending = True).groupby(['district']).head(5)
```

Ascending order (`rate_increase(%)`) after grouping by district, still does not work. Thanks

Comment: I managed to do with pandas as below:  ```df.groupby('district').apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(5, 'rate_increase(%)'))```  The tricky part was I had to change the `rate_increase(%)` into int type in order to make it work. Any pyspark solutions available? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lilly, 
You can read data from csv with pandas or create pandas dataframe like below and then convert it to spark dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = { 
    'district': ["Arba", "Arba", "Arba","Cebu", "Cebu"],
    'item': ['coil', 'pen', 'hat','oil','pen'],
    'rate_increase(%)': [500,-85,50,-40,1100]}
    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
ddf_1 = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
ddf_1.createOrReplaceTempView("ddf_1")

output = spark.sql("""

select district, item , `rate_increase(%)` from (
  select row_number() over (partition by district order by `rate_increase(%)` desc) as RowNum, district,item, `rate_increase(%)`  from ddf_1  where  `rate_increase(%)` > 0 )
where RowNum <= 5 order by district, RowNum

""")

output.show()

+--------+----+----------------+
|district|item|rate_increase(%)|
+--------+----+----------------+
|    Arba|coil|             500|
|    Arba| hat|              50|
|    Cebu| pen|            1100|
+--------+----+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind the query order of execution:

> From/Joins ->  Where -> Group by - > Having -> Select

The where clause `where RowNum <= 5` doesn't work because it doesn't know what is `RowNum`.

Try to use a sub-query block:

```
spark.sql("""

select district, item , `rate_increase(%)` from (
  select row_number() over (partition by district order by `rate_increase(%)` desc) as RowNum, district,item, `rate_increase(%)`  from ddf_1  where  `rate_increase(%)` > 0 )
where RowNum <= 5 order by district, RowNum

""").show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+----+----------------+
|district|item|rate_increase(%)|
+--------+----+----------------+
|    Arba|coil|             500|
|    Arba| hat|              50|
|    Cebu| pen|            1100|
+--------+----+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks.  ```order by `rate_increase(%)` desc``` is not working. It's not picking values by descending order. Is there an easy solution with pyspark dataframe   ```df = spark.sql('select district, item, `rate_increase(%)` from ddf_1 where v > 0')```   Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the correct answer. Check if your `rate_increase(%)` has the correct datatype

Comment: data type is object type and hence had to cast it to float type and completed the task using pandas as below.  If I have to use your solution,  how do I do that.  My data is read from csv actually.  Thanks